# Accordion list with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, accordion

I have the following stucture of categories in Woocommerce:

```
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-7 cat-parent"><a href="https://example.com/cat-parent">Cat parent</a>
       <ul class="children">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="https://example.com/cat-child-1">Cat child 1</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="https://example.com/cat-child-2">Cat child 2</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-12"><a href="https://example.com/cat-child-2">Cat child 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

I want to create collapsing categories, but when I click on **Cat parent** to collapse the list I am redirected to the **Cat parent** page.

```
CSS:
    ul.children { display:none; }

JS:
    $('.cat-parent a').click(function(e){

      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.parent().hasClass('cat-parent')) {
        $('.children').slideUp();
      }
      var sub = $this.parent().find('> .children');
      if($(sub).is(":hidden")){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(sub).slideDown();
      }
    });
```

Comment: you have to change `href="https://example.com/cat-parent"` to `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Yes, but you can't enter in the page of the Cat parent.

Comment: When you want to display the menu?

Comment: Children categories are hidden, when click on cat parent they are displayed and when click again on cat parent they are hidden. Now they collapse, but you are redirected to to the page. I want to be possible to be redirected to the cat parent page. Is it possible ?